# Web based printer status monitoring

Tags: monitoring, printer

I am looking for a simple solution to monitor the status of various printers/MFPs in the office and display the status on a HTML(or similar) page for office staff to view.

The monitoring does not need to be very comprehensive, just a simple online/offline would do. I am trying to stay away from any large monitoring software like Nagios.

Any recommendations?

Comment: I should add, we are an all Windows based shop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about setting up a CUPS print server and having your users view the status from it's web interface?  You wouldn't necessarily even have to have all the clients print through that print server as I think it can get some basic status info out when talking IPP to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

As mtinberg said, [CUPS](http://www.cups.org/index.php) should fit the bill.